# Time Complexity of Addition

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am new to calculating time complexity. I know if we have constant term we neglect that and if we have equation we take the highest power of the term like x^3+2x^2+n will have O(n^3). But what do we do when we have addition of these complexities? Like to be specific What is the time complexity of O(n) + O(sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since O(Sqrt(n)) is really O(n^(1/2)) and O(n) is O(n^1) following this logic the complexity of  O(n) + O(sqrt(n)) <= 2*O(n) = O(n)

Comment: To further expand on this, big-O notation just provides *an* upper bound for the time complexity. This means that O(n+sqrt(n)), O(n), O(n^2), etc. are all valid. However, you usually want to provide a tight upper bound, ie. one that matches the actual time complexity as closely as possible. How detailed you make your upper bound is up to you and the context. In this case, since sqrt(n) is so much smaller than n at reasonably large numbers, O(n) would be the most common way to represent it.